# "status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Required Date parameter 'end' is not present"

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, curl, https

I work with a Java API and I get HTTP status 400 for a GET call. The API is presented,

```
@GetMapping("/findWithRange")
public ResponseEntity<List<Appointment>> findAllWithCreationRange(@RequestParam("start") Date start, @RequestParam("end") Date end) {

    List<Appointment> appointments = service.findAllWithCreationRange(start, end);

    if (Objects.isNull(appointments)) {
        ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok(appointments);
}
```

I make the `cURL` GET call,

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/appointments/findWithRange?start=2018-10-01&end=2018-10-15
```

I get the response,

```
{"timestamp":"2019-02-10T07:58:22.151+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Required Date parameter 'end' is not present","path":"/api/v1/appointments/findWithRange"}
```

It's telling that the `end` parameter is not presented in the call which seems is not correct. The repository and the service class is also provided,

```
@Repository
public interface AppointmentRepository extends CrudRepository<Appointment, Long> {

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Appointment WHERE appointment_date <= :creationDateTime", nativeQuery = true)
List<Appointment> findAllWithCreationDateTimeBefore(@Param("creationDateTime") Date creationDateTime);


@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Appointment WHERE appointment_date >= :startDate AND appointment_date <= :endDate", nativeQuery = true)
List<Appointment> findAllWithCreationRange(@Param("startDate") Date startDate, @Param("endDate") Date endDate);
}
```

The service class,

```
@Service
public class AppointmentService {
@Autowired
private AppointmentRepository repository;

public Optional<Appointment> findById(Long id) {
    return repository.findById(id);
}

public List<Appointment> findAll() {
    return (List<Appointment>) repository.findAll();
}

public List<Appointment> findAllWithCreationDateTimeBefore(Date date) {
    return (List<Appointment>) repository.findAllWithCreationDateTimeBefore(date);
}

public List<Appointment> findAllWithCreationRange(Date start, Date end) {
    return (List<Appointment>) repository.findAllWithCreationRange(start, end);
}

public Appointment save(Appointment appointment) {
    return repository.save(appointment);
}

public void deleteById(Long id) {
    repository.deleteById(id);
}

public void deleteAll() {
    repository.deleteAll();
}
}
```

I have also tried to make the call with `&&`,

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/appointments/findWithRange?start=2018-10-01&&end=2018-10-15
```

and this returns the same response and not helpful. What I miss here and to run to properly?

Note: I have a similar endpoint that works fine which made me more curious.

```
// curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/appointments/creationDateTime?start=2018-10-01 | jq

    @GetMapping("/creationDateTime")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Appointment>> findAllWithCreationDateTimeBefore(@RequestParam("start") Date date) {

        List<Appointment> appointment = service.findAllWithCreationDateTimeBefore(date);

        if (Objects.isNull(appointment)) {
            ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(appointment);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are not suppling DateFormat without which String cannot be converted to date.

Use `@DateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")` like :

```
@GetMapping("/findWithRange")
public ResponseEntity<List<Appointment>> findAllWithCreationRange(@RequestParam("start") @DateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd") Date start, @RequestParam("end") @DateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd") Date end) {

    List<Appointment> appointments = service.findAllWithCreationRange(start, end);

    if (Objects.isNull(appointments)) {
        ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok(appointments);
}
```

Comment: The annotation should be `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")` and it doesn't solve the issue. I get the error `No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.Date] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.sql.Date]"`. Note I used `java.sql.Date` in the API